# How to take a function passed as a template class and turn it into a constexpr callable (C++, template meta-programming)?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I have an external function that is passed as a class via a template parameter to another class. I want to call that external function in a constexpr member function and static assert its output value. The code is shown below, where I commented out the line: `static_assert(F{}(f_args) == false);`

Everything else works, where `f_args` is constructed during **compile-time**. I can use anything C++14 or later.

**I want to evaluate the function type `F` with the `f_args` constructed at the end of the template recursion, which requires me to take the template parameter `F` and turn it into something that's a constexpr invokable. How do I do that?**

```
    template <class F, class IK, class PK, class Levels, class Is>
    class Coiterate;

    template <class F, class IK, class PK, class... Levels, class... Is>
    class Coiterate<F, IK, PK, std::tuple<Levels...>, std::tuple<Is...>>
    {
    private:
        std::tuple<Levels&...> const m_levelsTuple;
        F const m_comparisonHelper;

    public:
        explicit inline Coiterate(
            F f,
            Levels&... levels)
            : m_levelsTuple(std::tie(levels...))
            , m_comparisonHelper(f)
        {
            // run a compile-time validation
            validate_boolean_args();
        }

        // Assume this work as expected. A tuple of booleans corresponding to each level
        static constexpr auto ordered_mask_tuple = std::make_tuple(is_level_ordered<Levels>()...);

        template <std::size_t I, typename... Args>
        constexpr void validate_boolean_helper(std::tuple<Args...> f_args)
        {
            // Check if the current recursion depth (I) is less than the number of elements in Mask.
            if constexpr (I < sizeof(ordered_mask_tuple))
            {
                validate_boolean_helper<I + 1, Args...>(std::tuple_cat(f_args, std::tuple<bool>(false)));
            }
            else
            {
                // When we reach the end of recursion (base case), call the function object F with the constructed boolean arguments.
                static_assert(sizeof...(Args) == sizeof...(Levels), "Number of arguments must be equal to number of levels");

                // XXX: This line results in the following errors.
                // static_assert(F{}(f_args) == false, "Function F should return false for the given arguments.");
            }
        }

        constexpr void validate_boolean_args()
        {
            validate_boolean_helper<0>(std::tuple<>());
        }
```

##### Pseudocode example of how I would initialize the class `Coiterate`

```
// this is a function defined by the user
auto fn = [](std::tuple<bool, bool, bool, bool> t) constexpr
    { return (std::get<0>(t) || std::get<2>(t)) || (std::get<1>(t) || std::get<3>(t)); };

// the function is passed as a template parameter and as an argument to the constructor
Coiterate<std::function<bool(std::tuple<bool, bool, bool, bool>)>, ...>
        coiter(fn, ...);
```

##### Example compiler-error

```
In file included from /Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/test/source/coiteration_test.cpp:17:
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/include/xsparse/level_capabilities/co_iteration.hpp:245:31: error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
                static_assert(F{}(f_args) == false, "Function F should return false for the given arguments.");
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/include/xsparse/level_capabilities/co_iteration.hpp:235:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'xsparse::level_capabilities::Coiterate<std::function<bool (std::tuple<bool, bool>)>, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::tuple<xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>>, std::tuple<>>::validate_boolean_helper<2UL, bool, bool>' requested here
                validate_boolean_helper<I + 1, Args...>(std::tuple_cat(f_args, std::tuple<bool>(false)));
                ^
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/include/xsparse/level_capabilities/co_iteration.hpp:235:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'xsparse::level_capabilities::Coiterate<std::function<bool (std::tuple<bool, bool>)>, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::tuple<xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>>, std::tuple<>>::validate_boolean_helper<1UL, bool>' requested here
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/include/xsparse/level_capabilities/co_iteration.hpp:251:13: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'xsparse::level_capabilities::Coiterate<std::function<bool (std::tuple<bool, bool>)>, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::tuple<xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>>, std::tuple<>>::validate_boolean_helper<0UL>' requested here
            validate_boolean_helper<0>(std::tuple<>());
            ^
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/include/xsparse/level_capabilities/co_iteration.hpp:206:13: note: in instantiation of member function 'xsparse::level_capabilities::Coiterate<std::function<bool (std::tuple<bool, bool>)>, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::tuple<xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>>, std::tuple<>>::validate_boolean_args' requested here
            validate_boolean_args();
            ^
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/test/source/coiteration_test.cpp:37:9: note: in instantiation of member function 'xsparse::level_capabilities::Coiterate<std::function<bool (std::tuple<bool, bool>)>, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::tuple<xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>>, std::tuple<>>::Coiterate' requested here
        coiter(fn, s1, s2);
        ^
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/include/xsparse/level_capabilities/co_iteration.hpp:245:31: note: non-literal type 'std::function<bool (std::tuple<bool, bool>)>' cannot be used in a constant expression
                static_assert(F{}(f_args) == false, "Function F should return false for the given arguments.");
                              ^
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/include/xsparse/level_capabilities/co_iteration.hpp:245:31: error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
                static_assert(F{}(f_args) == false, "Function F should return false for the given arguments.");
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/include/xsparse/level_capabilities/co_iteration.hpp:235:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'xsparse::level_capabilities::Coiterate<std::function<bool (std::tuple<bool, bool, bool>)>, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::tuple<xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>>, std::tuple<>>::validate_boolean_helper<3UL, bool, bool, bool>' requested here
                validate_boolean_helper<I + 1, Args...>(std::tuple_cat(f_args, std::tuple<bool>(false)));
                ^
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/include/xsparse/level_capabilities/co_iteration.hpp:235:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'xsparse::level_capabilities::Coiterate<std::function<bool (std::tuple<bool, bool, bool>)>, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::tuple<xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>>, std::tuple<>>::validate_boolean_helper<2UL, bool, bool>' requested here
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/include/xsparse/level_capabilities/co_iteration.hpp:235:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'xsparse::level_capabilities::Coiterate<std::function<bool (std::tuple<bool, bool, bool>)>, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::tuple<xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>>, std::tuple<>>::validate_boolean_helper<1UL, bool>' requested here
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/include/xsparse/level_capabilities/co_iteration.hpp:251:13: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'xsparse::level_capabilities::Coiterate<std::function<bool (std::tuple<bool, bool, bool>)>, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::tuple<xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>>, std::tuple<>>::validate_boolean_helper<0UL>' requested here
            validate_boolean_helper<0>(std::tuple<>());
            ^
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/include/xsparse/level_capabilities/co_iteration.hpp:206:13: note: in instantiation of member function 'xsparse::level_capabilities::Coiterate<std::function<bool (std::tuple<bool, bool, bool>)>, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::tuple<xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>>, std::tuple<>>::validate_boolean_args' requested here
            validate_boolean_args();
            ^
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/test/source/coiteration_test.cpp:83:9: note: in instantiation of member function 'xsparse::level_capabilities::Coiterate<std::function<bool (std::tuple<bool, bool, bool>)>, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::tuple<xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>>, std::tuple<>>::Coiterate' requested here
        coiter(fn, s1, s2, s3);
        ^
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/include/xsparse/level_capabilities/co_iteration.hpp:245:31: note: non-literal type 'std::function<bool (std::tuple<bool, bool, bool>)>' cannot be used in a constant expression
                static_assert(F{}(f_args) == false, "Function F should return false for the given arguments.");
                              ^
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/include/xsparse/level_capabilities/co_iteration.hpp:245:31: error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
                static_assert(F{}(f_args) == false, "Function F should return false for the given arguments.");
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/include/xsparse/level_capabilities/co_iteration.hpp:235:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'xsparse::level_capabilities::Coiterate<std::function<bool (std::tuple<bool, bool, bool, bool>)>, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::tuple<xsparse::levels::singleton<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::singleton<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>>, std::tuple<>>::validate_boolean_helper<4UL, bool, bool, bool, bool>' requested here
                validate_boolean_helper<I + 1, Args...>(std::tuple_cat(f_args, std::tuple<bool>(false)));
                ^
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/include/xsparse/level_capabilities/co_iteration.hpp:235:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'xsparse::level_capabilities::Coiterate<std::function<bool (std::tuple<bool, bool, bool, bool>)>, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::tuple<xsparse::levels::singleton<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::singleton<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>>, std::tuple<>>::validate_boolean_helper<3UL, bool, bool, bool>' requested here
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/include/xsparse/level_capabilities/co_iteration.hpp:235:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'xsparse::level_capabilities::Coiterate<std::function<bool (std::tuple<bool, bool, bool, bool>)>, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::tuple<xsparse::levels::singleton<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::singleton<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>>, std::tuple<>>::validate_boolean_helper<2UL, bool, bool>' requested here
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/include/xsparse/level_capabilities/co_iteration.hpp:235:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'xsparse::level_capabilities::Coiterate<std::function<bool (std::tuple<bool, bool, bool, bool>)>, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::tuple<xsparse::levels::singleton<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::singleton<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>>, std::tuple<>>::validate_boolean_helper<1UL, bool>' requested here
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/include/xsparse/level_capabilities/co_iteration.hpp:251:13: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'xsparse::level_capabilities::Coiterate<std::function<bool (std::tuple<bool, bool, bool, bool>)>, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::tuple<xsparse::levels::singleton<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::singleton<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>>, std::tuple<>>::validate_boolean_helper<0UL>' requested here
            validate_boolean_helper<0>(std::tuple<>());
            ^
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/include/xsparse/level_capabilities/co_iteration.hpp:206:13: note: in instantiation of member function 'xsparse::level_capabilities::Coiterate<std::function<bool (std::tuple<bool, bool, bool, bool>)>, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::tuple<xsparse::levels::singleton<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::singleton<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>>, std::tuple<>>::validate_boolean_args' requested here
            validate_boolean_args();
            ^
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/test/source/coiteration_test.cpp:144:9: note: in instantiation of member function 'xsparse::level_capabilities::Coiterate<std::function<bool (std::tuple<bool, bool, bool, bool>)>, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::tuple<xsparse::levels::singleton<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::singleton<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>>, std::tuple<>>::Coiterate' requested here
        coiter(fn, s1, s2, s3, s4);
        ^
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/include/xsparse/level_capabilities/co_iteration.hpp:245:31: note: non-literal type 'std::function<bool (std::tuple<bool, bool, bool, bool>)>' cannot be used in a constant expression
                static_assert(F{}(f_args) == false, "Function F should return false for the given arguments.");
                              ^
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/include/xsparse/level_capabilities/co_iteration.hpp:245:31: error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
                static_assert(F{}(f_args) == false, "Function F should return false for the given arguments.");
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/include/xsparse/level_capabilities/co_iteration.hpp:235:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'xsparse::level_capabilities::Coiterate<std::function<bool (std::tuple<bool, bool>)>, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::tuple<xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::hashed<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long, xsparse::util::container_traits<std::vector, std::unordered_set, std::unordered_map>, xsparse::level_properties<false, false, false, false, false>>>, std::tuple<>>::validate_boolean_helper<2UL, bool, bool>' requested here
                validate_boolean_helper<I + 1, Args...>(std::tuple_cat(f_args, std::tuple<bool>(false)));
                ^
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/include/xsparse/level_capabilities/co_iteration.hpp:235:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'xsparse::level_capabilities::Coiterate<std::function<bool (std::tuple<bool, bool>)>, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::tuple<xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::hashed<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long, xsparse::util::container_traits<std::vector, std::unordered_set, std::unordered_map>, xsparse::level_properties<false, false, false, false, false>>>, std::tuple<>>::validate_boolean_helper<1UL, bool>' requested here
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/include/xsparse/level_capabilities/co_iteration.hpp:251:13: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'xsparse::level_capabilities::Coiterate<std::function<bool (std::tuple<bool, bool>)>, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::tuple<xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::hashed<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long, xsparse::util::container_traits<std::vector, std::unordered_set, std::unordered_map>, xsparse::level_properties<false, false, false, false, false>>>, std::tuple<>>::validate_boolean_helper<0UL>' requested here
            validate_boolean_helper<0>(std::tuple<>());
            ^
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/include/xsparse/level_capabilities/co_iteration.hpp:206:13: note: in instantiation of member function 'xsparse::level_capabilities::Coiterate<std::function<bool (std::tuple<bool, bool>)>, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::tuple<xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::hashed<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long, xsparse::util::container_traits<std::vector, std::unordered_set, std::unordered_map>, xsparse::level_properties<false, false, false, false, false>>>, std::tuple<>>::validate_boolean_args' requested here
            validate_boolean_args();
            ^
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/test/source/coiteration_test.cpp:235:9: note: in instantiation of member function 'xsparse::level_capabilities::Coiterate<std::function<bool (std::tuple<bool, bool>)>, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::tuple<xsparse::levels::dense<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long>, xsparse::levels::hashed<std::tuple<>, unsigned long, unsigned long, xsparse::util::container_traits<std::vector, std::unordered_set, std::unordered_map>, xsparse::level_properties<false, false, false, false, false>>>, std::tuple<>>::Coiterate' requested here
        coiter(fn, dense_level, hash_level);
        ^
/Users/adam2392/Documents/xsparse/include/xsparse/level_capabilities/co_iteration.hpp:245:31: note: non-literal type 'std::function<bool (std::tuple<bool, bool>)>' cannot be used in a constant expression
                static_assert(F{}(f_args) == false, "Function F should return false for the given arguments.");
                              ^
4 errors generated.
```

Comment: What do you mean by: _I have an external function that is passed as a class_?

Comment: @Amolgorithm I edited the question to provide an example of how the class would be initialized.

Comment: It seems you construct a tuple of boolean, so why not `static_assert(F{}(std::tuple((std::type_identity<Levels>(), false)...)));`?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean just invoking constexpr function via template parameter, 
something like this could be done:

```cpp
#include <tuple>

template <class F>
class Eval {
private:
    const F func_;

public:
    inline constexpr
    explicit Eval(F f) : func_(f) {
        validate_bool_f(std::make_tuple<>());
    }

    template <class... Args>
    constexpr void validate_bool_f(std::tuple<Args...> rhs) noexcept {
        static_assert(F{}(rhs), "Function returned false");
    }
};

int main(int,char**) {
    constexpr auto f =
        []<typename... Args>(const std::tuple<Args...>& args)
        {
            return false;
        };
    ;
    Eval<decltype(f)> c(f);
}
```

Store function as constexpr variable and pass it's type with decltype.

Comment: This doesn't work because the compiler-errors I linked do not recognized `F` as constexpr `error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression`

Comment: @ajl123 Yes it would behave like that as `f` returns false. The main point of this code is the way to pass the constexpr function's type which I said before and defining constructor as constexpr constructor.

Comment: I misunderstood maybe. I have tested this code as only C++20 clang, gcc both, but not other. Is C++14 is which you are using?

Comment: The constructor must be non constexpr because it is passing in some objects that are only known at runtime I believe. Yes I need to use older version of C++ for now, so C++14 would be ideal.

Comment: This also doesn't work for C++17: https://godbolt.org/z/EqeY3nv6n